# Audit users actions in Php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, logging, audit

I am developing admin section for the project in laravel 5. Where I have multiple administrators and a super admin. In this project, a super admin can audit the sub-administrators actions.

Now super admin wants to check that what are the other administrators doing on admin panel.

**Example:**
An administrator updated user information like address, phone number or email. How super admin will come to know that which administrator did this and who was the user which was updated by the administrator.

What should be the best practice to do this should I save each and every action to the database table? or any best practice?

Comment: Try to manage activity log of each query

Comment: use a audit table

Comment: I think the best one is to use model events if a user is updated then check if it is a sub manager who updated it then add a row in the activity table that you should create ;)

Comment: well you should have a log model .. where every action saves a log ..

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new table to store all the actions performed by admins.

Your new table should have fields to store following details

`who` - `The person who performed an action`

`what` - `what action he/she performed(update, delete)`

`when` - `when the action is performed`

`on whom` - `on which user the action is performed`

Now you have to create `observers` on all the models which you want to track(users)

see - [laravel Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers)

Your observer should have all the methods for actions which an admin performs(create, store, update, delete)

Your observer method should record the action performed by that admin to your newly created table.

Super admin can view the entries in this table to track admins behavior.

Comment: @user7597883 If you like this answer you should consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of create one Observer for each model as our frind said, you can create a single one passing the "Model" class as argument.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).